# Can someone explain why this isn't valid implementation?

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism

```
public class ServiceCodeController : ControllerBase {
    // the red squiggly under IJobRepository is saying it's not convertible
    private LazyRepo<IJobRepository> _domainRepo2; 
}

public class LazyRepo<TRepo> where TRepo : IRepository<IDomainEntity> { ... }

public interface IJobRepository : IRepository<JobDomain>, IListRepository { ... }

public interface IRepository<T> : IRepositoryRead<T>, 
    IRepositoryCreate<T>, 
    IRepositoryDelete<T>, 
    IRepositoryUpdate<T> 
    where T : IDomainEntity { ... }

public class JobDomain : BaseDomainEntity { ... }

public abstract class BaseDomainEntity : IDomainEntity, 
    IDomainEntityModifiable,
    IDomainEntityActivatable, 
    IDomainEntityNameable { ... }
```

My thinking is that LazyRepo takes *something* that implements `IRepository` that takes *something* that implements `IDomainEntity`. As you can see, `IJobRepository` implements `IRepository` that takes `JobDomain` that inherits from `BaseDomainEntity` which, at long last, implements `IDomainEntity`.

For my money, this *should* work for setting up the LazyRepo class.

Can someone explain to me why I'm getting this error? *The type 'IJobRepository' cannot be used as type parameter 'TRepo' in the generic type or method 'LazyRepo'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'IJobRepository' to 'IRepository'*

Comment: Can you provide more complete sample code?  With using statements.

Comment: I think this will work if you make `IRepository` covariant by adding the `out` keyword before `T`.

Comment: @TyreeJackson the code inside the classes are irrelevant, which is why I didn't post them. Nothing in the implementation should matter for why I can't do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is where the concepts of `contravariance` and `covariance` come in.

> A covariant interface allows its methods to return more derived types than those specified in the interface. A contravariant interface allows its methods to accept parameters of less derived types than those specified in the interface.

source:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465120.aspx

You fix this by using the `in` and `out` keywords:

```
public interface IRepository<out T> : ...
```

(source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx)

Comment: I actually found a fix elsewhere, but what you posted works. It's funny, I stumbled across those concepts the other day, but got busy and never read exactly the articles you posted. Guess I shoulda taken the time that day. =) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class ServiceCodeController : ControllerBase {
    // the red squiggly under IJobRepository is saying it's not convertible
    private LazyRepo<IJobRepository, JobDomain> _domainRepo2; 
}

public class LazyRepo<TRepo, TDomain> where TRepo : IRepository<TDomain> where TDomain : IDomainEntity {  }
```

By specifying the TDomain as a generic parameter constrained to IDomainEntity and constraining TRepo to IRepository of TDomain, you provide all of the information needed by the compiler to resolve IJobRepository and JobDomain as arguments for LazyRepo.  This provides an alternative to using variance.

The issue has to deal with the fact that `IRepository<IDomainEntity>` != `IRepository<JobDomain>`.  It's the classic fruit bowl issue that's been discussed on SO.  However, if you substitute a generic parameter for IDomainEntity, then you can fully qualify the run-time definition of TRepo for LazyRepo.

For completeness, here is a modified version of your code that compiles:

```
public class ControllerBase {}
public interface IDomainEntity {}
public interface IDomainEntityModifiable {}
public interface IDomainEntityActivatable {}
public interface IDomainEntityNameable {}
public interface IListRepository {}
public interface IRepositoryRead<out TDomain> where TDomain : IDomainEntity {}
public interface IRepositoryCreate<out TDomain> where TDomain : IDomainEntity {}
public interface IRepositoryDelete<out TDomain> where TDomain : IDomainEntity {}
public interface IRepositoryUpdate<out TDomain> where TDomain : IDomainEntity {}
public class ServiceCodeController : ControllerBase 
{
    private LazyRepo<IJobRepository, JobDomain> _domainRepo2; 
}

public class LazyRepo<TRepo, TDomain> where TRepo : IRepository<TDomain> where TDomain : IDomainEntity {  }

public interface IJobRepository : IRepository<JobDomain>, IListRepository {  }

public interface IRepository<out T> : IRepositoryRead<T>, 
    IRepositoryCreate<T>, 
    IRepositoryDelete<T>, 
    IRepositoryUpdate<T> 
    where T : IDomainEntity {  }

public class JobDomain : BaseDomainEntity { }

public abstract class BaseDomainEntity : IDomainEntity, 
    IDomainEntityModifiable,
    IDomainEntityActivatable, 
    IDomainEntityNameable {  }
```

Comment: "Try this" without any explanation of what you did, why it may work, or the concepts behind it is not a good way to answer a question.

Comment: @RonBeyer I've added an explanation.

Comment: Note that this approach also works for classes, where contravariance and covariance are not supported.